# Path must be a string. Received undefined after upgrading my cordova to 7.1.0

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

> E:\ionic template\gb\IonicMaterialDesign>cordova platform add android
>
> Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.3.0 Adding android
>   project... `Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
>           Path: platforms\android
>           Package: com.grabhalal.ghadmin
>           Name: gb
>           Activity: MainActivity
>           Android target: android-26 Subproject Path: CordovaLib Android project created with cordova-android@6.3.0 Installing`
>
> "cordova-plugin-app-event" for android Installing
>
> "cordova-plugin-background-mode" for android android-sdk version check
>   failed ("E:\ionic
>   template\gb\IonicMaterialDesign\platforms\android\cordova\android_sdk_version"),
>   continuing anyways.

`Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-device@1.1.2"
 already fetched, using that version. Installing`

> `"cordova-plugin-device" for android Installing`
>
> `"cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" for android Subproject Path:`
>
> CordovaLib After much discussion and analysis of the market, we have
>   decided to discontinue support for Android 4.0 (ICS) in Crosswalk
>   starting with version 20. So the minSdkVersion of Cordova project is
>   configured to 16 by default.

`Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-device"

> already installed on android.Installing`
>
> `"cordova-plugin-globalization" for android Installing`
>
> `"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" for android Installing`
>
> `"cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android Installing`
>
> `"cordova-plugin-statusbar" for android Installing
>
> `"cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android This plugin is only applicable
>   for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a
>   previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the
>   whitelist will be built in.`
>
> `Installing "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" for android Subproject`
>
> Path: CordovaLib 
>   `Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" for android`
>   `installing external dependencies via npm npm install of external`
>
> dependencies ok

`Error: Path must be a string. Received undefined`

Answer (score 9):

the same thing happened with me after the update, and in the end, what solved it was removing the "config-file" tags from my config.xml

Comment: and how did you define the configs? i am using phonegap cloud build and need this configurations - and I cannot change the plist files;)

Comment: inside the config.xml file i had this line :  " <config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application" mode="merge"> 
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" />
</config-file> "      i removed it and the problem was solved , i use cordova cli

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Cordova Custom Config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin instead of `<config-file>` elements fixed this issue for me.